# Is this an appropriate way to provide callbacks for an embedded JS library?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

I have a small SaaS product that offers js code to create an embedded form on a webpage. The code I have them copy and paste looks like this:

```
<div class="form-container" data-form="form-22" ></div>
<script src="https://example.com/embed-code.js" />
```

I want to provide a callback mechanism so that their own javascript can be notified when the form is submitted.

The way I've been implementing it so far is by telling them to create a global variable with the requisite callback functions:

```
var form_callbacks = {
  submitted: function(){...}
}
```

My embed code then looks for `window.form_callbacks` and triggers them when provided.

I'm not really a client-side JS developer, but asking someone to create a global variable seems like the wrong way to do it.

Is there a more standard way of doing this?

Comment: Can you provide an example of how your user(s) might use your library? If it's invoked similarly to jQuery then it makes sense to simply provide the callback as an argument passed to your library functions/methods. Otherwise perhaps provide event triggers that user-functions can listen for, and react to. But without some idea of what's going on it's hard - if not impossible - to provide practical solutions that might also be of benefit to future users.

Comment: What if they have multiple forms one one page? Your approach would break down fast.

Comment: Provide functions that take functions as parameters to then store them, e.g. MyCodebase.on("submit",function(){});

Comment: Oh I guess that would work if their js went after my include. Ok, I'll think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is to have your library instantiate a global object, in a namespace quickly identifiable (i.e. the name of your product), and offer a *method* to subscribe to events. Don't force the user to declare any global variables.

```
ComExampleForms.get("form-22").subscribe("submit", function(e) {…});
```

Comment: Ah ok, that makes a lot of sense.  something like this: `Example.on("form:submit", function(form, data) { doSomething(); });`